# Populate form field with AJAX query

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, ajaxform

I would like to populate a django form field each time a dropdown value is selected inside a specific field.

***Example :***

I have a list of businesses (business A, business B, ...) and a list of countries. Each business is located in a specific country.

```
Business A --> France
Business B --> Germany
Business C --> England
```

In my form, when I select a specific business in my `dropdown list`, I would like to populate immediatly the country field with the associated country. If the business change, the associated country too.

I'm using Django 1.11.18

***The context :***

In my code, `MemberState` corresponds to the Country as my example above and `RBI` corresponds to the business.

***My Model :***

```
class MemberState(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name=_('Name'))
    code = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name=_('Code'))

class RBI(models.Model):

    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name=_('Short name'), unique=True)
    member_state = models.ForeignKey(MemberState, verbose_name=_('Member State'))
    ...
```

***My Form :***

```
class FinalProductSearchForm(forms.Form):

    releasing_body = ShortNameModelChoiceField(queryset=RBI.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('short_name'), required=False,
            widget=forms.Select(), empty_label=_('Select'), label=_('Releasing Body/Institution'))
    member_state = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MemberState.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('name'), required=False,
            widget=forms.Select(), empty_label=_('Select'), label=_('Member state'))
    ...
```

I would like to select a `releasing_body` in my form and prefill the member_state field associated. Each time I change the `realeasing_body` it loads the associated `member_state`.

I tried some things in Django but I need AJAX request. Unfortunatly, I have never done this kind of things.

***My work with AJAX part :***

So, this is my first try (which doesn't work) :

I created this function in my views.py file :

```
def ajax_member_state_request(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        release_body = request.GET.get('releasing_body', None)
        print(release_body)
        member_state_ini = ReleaseBodyInstitution.objects.values_list('member_state', flat=True).get(id=release_body)
        print(member_state_ini)
        member_state = MemberState.objects.get(id=member_state_ini)
        print(member_state)
    return JsonResponse({'member_state': member_state})
```

In my urls.py file, I added :

```
url(r'^finalproduct/list/$', FinalProductListView.as_view(),
    name='finalproduct-list'),
url(r'^finalproduct/list/ajax_member_state_request/$', views.ajax_member_state_request, name='ajax_member_state_request'),
```

And finally in my HTML file :

```
<form id="providerForm" data-provider-url="{% url 'ajax_member_state_request' %}" class="navbar-search" method="GET" action="{{ url }}">

{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ search_form.releasing_body|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ search_form.member_state|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="{% trans 'Search' %}" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="clear" value="Reset" onclick="clearForm(this.form);">
</form>
```

The AJAX part looks like this :

```
$("#id_releasing_body").change(function () {
  var url = $("#providerForm").attr("data-provider-url");
  var releasingBodyId = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      'releasing_body': releasingBodyId
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $("#id_member_state").val(data.member_state);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Since you clearly have a URL with that `name` attribute, I would guess that you've namespaced your URLs, in which case you need to do it like this: `data-provider-url="{% url <namespace>:'ajax_member_state_request' %}"`. See documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls

Comment: Ok, by adding the namespace, I don't have the issue about `reverse url`. But it doesn't display the `member_state` associated to `releasing_body` selected --> AJAX part or my django function.

Comment: I just noticed your Ajax view references `ReleaseBodyInstitution.objects.get(id=release_body).member_state` - yet your model is called `RBI`. Is your Ajax request throwing an error? (Check the Network tab in your browser.)

Comment: yes it's `RBI.objects.get(id=release_body).member_state` in my code it's well-written. I apologize and update my question.

Comment: Does the URL pattern `r'^ajax/ajax_member_state_request/$'` have been listed in the list of patterns Django tried?

Comment: @Essex I've edited your question in order to remove the URL related issue, which  is not a problem anymore

Comment: Yes thank you ! The issue that I have is in my django function part. I edit my question.

Comment: So the latest issue is the one about not being JSON serializable? That's because you're trying to send the entire model instance object. Looks like you only need the id, so just send that as the response.

Comment: Ok, it's better. The only thing now is that my `member_state` field becomes empty when I select a `release_body` object. But it displays the `member_state` in the console well.

Comment: I think you would need `$("#id_member_state").val(data.member_state);` in your success callback, assuming the relevant form control has id `id_member_state`, and that your Ajax view is as above but now just passing the id.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes, but the field `Member State` still blank even if I can display in the console the object.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement a view that given a business name returns a `JsonResponse` with the country (following your example).

With that in place in the `success` section of the ajax request set the `value` of the country form field.

The view:

```
def contry_for_bussines(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        member_state = ReleaseBodyInstitution.objects.get(id=release_body).member_state
    return JsonResponse({'member_state': member_state})
```

In the ajax

```
$("#id_releasing_body").change(function () {
  var url = $("#providerForm").attr("data-provider-url");
  var releasingBodyId = $(this).val();

  $.get(url, {'releasing_body': releasingBodyId}, function(data){
       $("#id_member_state").text(data.member_state);
  });    
});
```

Comment: I agree this is a better way of doing it. I'm reluctant to say it's an answer though, I'd prefer to identify what the issue is in the OP's code.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yeah, I wrote this responding to *But I'm sure than my AJAX part is not good.*

Comment: I tried your code and I tried to make some improvments in mine. I edited in my question the urls.py file to show you paths. In your edit, it should be a `$.get(url ...)` because it's a search. 

The issue is : `$("#id_member_state").value(data.member_state);` (index):3294 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).value is not a function

Comment: Fixed. Have you only one urls file? Have you checked you are adding all urlpatterns?

Comment: Yes, it should work. I'm looking for my django function to see if all is good.

Comment: `text(data.member_state);` is unresolved member_state. It doesn't find the variable I assume

Comment: @Essex as I mentioned above you should be using `.val` rather than `text`, since you're trying to set the value of a form control

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes I used `.val` following your comment. But the field still remains blank

Comment: could you help me with this?
I fixed one problem but the duplicated element still appear please see this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69572212/duplicated-element-after-ajax-run

Answer (score 0):

Check this approach if it helps, I followed those steps for my project and successfully populated choicefields with AJAX request. The only problem is the form is not binding when submitted despite a value is selected in all fields (working on that now)

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html