# Duplicated element after Ajax run

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-forms

I am trying to Auto-complete form fields using Ajax and Jquery.
First I used Django and the views.py function is:

```
def CreateWellMon(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SurveillanceDesPuits_F(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('WellMonitor')
    else:
        try:
            PUITS_id = request.GET.get('PUITS')
            record = SurveillanceDesPuits.objects.filter(PUITS_id__id__exact=PUITS_id)[:1]
            record2 = SurveillanceDesPuits.objects.get(id= record[0].id)
            form = SurveillanceDesPuits_F(instance=record2)
        
            return render(request, 'measure/Surveill_Wells/Add_wellMntr2.html', {'form': form})
        except:
            record2 = SurveillanceDesPuits.objects.all().first()
            form = SurveillanceDesPuits_F(instance=record2)
            return render(request, 'measure/Surveill_Wells/Add_wellMntr2.html', {'form': form})
```

So here I just selected the last record from the database at first. After when the user chooses a Well it reloads the last record of the element.

my HTML page code is:

```
{% extends 'Home/base2.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div class="w3-panel w3-border w3-light-grey w3-round-large sizeA"> <h2>Well Information</h2> <h2 class="border-bottom pb-1 mb-3"><b>Add New montoring record 3</b></h2> </div>

{% if form %}

<div class="border p-3 mb-3 mt-3 w3-round-large w3-light-grey border-dark">
    <form method="POST" id="SurveillanceDesPuits_F" data-record-url="{% url 'Add_wellMntr' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
          <!-- form  from views.py-->
        <div class="border p-2 mb-3 mt-3 border-secondary">
                    <div class="form-row">
                <div id= "PUITS" class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    
                    {{form.PUITS|as_crispy_field}}

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.CS |as_crispy_field}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.MODE|as_crispy_field}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.SITUATION |as_crispy_field}}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.DATE_TEST|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div id='DUSE' class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                   {{ form.DUSE|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                

                <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.PRES_TBG|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                    {{ form.PRES_CSG|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
            </div>     



            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-8 mb-0">
                    {{ form.OBSERVATION|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-success mb-4" type="submit" value="ADD Record">
    </form>
    </div>

{% endif %}


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id_PUITS").change(function(){
    var url = $("#SurveillanceDesPuits_F").attr("data-record-url");  
    var PUITSId = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET' ,               
        url: url,              
        data: {
          'PUITS': PUITSId     
                 },
        success: function (data){
        $('#SurveillanceDesPuits_F').html(data);
        }
        });
                                 });
        return false;
                        }); </script>

{% endblock content %}
```

The problem is that after selecting a well the AJAX duplicates some elements in the page as described in the photo.
and how I do to solve this and keep the selected well because it is a choice field?

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please show your views and the html for the url in ajax  request ?

Comment: I already did, and if you mean the urls.py
    path('Add_wellMntr/', MeasureV.CreateWellMon, name='Add_wellMntr'),

Comment: Did you check what does your server bring back  ?  Do `console.log(data)` see what it prints inside browsers elements tab.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bridge')
    at (index):1416
jquery.js:9725 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
send @ jquery.js:9725
ajax @ jquery.js:9434

Comment: I solved one problem that is doesn't keep the choice by deleting the to_field='WellID' in the models.py.

Now, still, just the duplicated problem, and this issue will be solved completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I made a change in models.py, I deleted `to_field='WellID'`, so it will keep the selected well after the AJAX call.

```
class SurveillanceDesPuits(models.Model):
    PUITS    =  models.ForeignKey(Surveill_Wells , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    DATE_TEST=  models.DateField()
    ....
```

then I changed the views.py:

```
def CreateWellMon(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SurveillanceDesPuits_F(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('WellMonitor')
    else:
        try:
            PUITS_id = request.GET.get('PUITS')
            record2 = SurveillanceDesPuits.objects.filter(PUITS_id__id__exact=PUITS_id)[:1]
            return JsonResponse({'record2': list(record2.values())}, safe=False)
        except:
            form = SurveillanceDesPuits_F()
            return render(request, 'measure/Surveill_Wells/Add_wellMntr2.html', {'form': form})
```

the last change is in the HTML page and the ajax code call will be as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'GET' ,               
            url: url,              
            data: {'PUITS': PUITSId },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response){           
                var  response = JSON.parse(response);
                const object = response[0]
    
                $("#id_PUITS").val(object.fields.PUITS);
                $("#id_DATE_TEST").val(object.fields.DATE_TEST);
                $("#id_MODE").val(object.fields.MODE);
                $("#id_CS").val(object.fields.CS);
                $("#id_SITUATION").val(object.fields.SITUATION);
                $("#id_DUSE").val(object.fields.DUSE);
                $("#id_PRES_TBG").val(object.fields.PRES_TBG);
                $("#id_PRES_CSG").val(object.fields.PRES_CSG);
                $("#id_PRES_AVD").val(object.fields.PRES_AVD);
                $("#id_RESEAU_GL").val(object.fields.RESEAU_GL);
                $("#id_ANNULAIRE_TECH").val(object.fields.ANNULAIRE_TECH);
                $("#id_OBSERVATION").val(object.fields.OBSERVATION);
                $("#id_Controle_Pression_ENSP").val(object.fields.Controle_Pression_ENSP);
                $("#id_Test_Puits").val(object.fields.Test_Puits);
                $("#id_Controle_Pression_DP").val(object.fields.Controle_Pression_DP);
            },
    
            });
            return false;
            });
    </script>
```

this will avoid the duplicated page caused by the

```
$("#SurveillanceDesPuits_F").html(response);
```

Many thanks